# RMarkdown V2 Shiny Document and dplyr

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, r-markdown

I'm trying to use an input selection for rmarkdown v2 with dplyr to select certain columns to be reported. The selected column will then be used in a formula given to the nls() function to determine the value of some constant C.

My code is as follows:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
date: "Wednesday, June 18, 2014"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r, echo=TRUE}
require(dplyr)
#Some sample random data in a data.frame:
test=data.frame(A=runif(n=10),V=runif(n=10),N=runif(n=10))

#Input box to choose desired column
inputPanel(
  selectInput('sample.choice', label = 'Choose Columns',
              choices = c('V Sample'='V',
                          'N Sample'='N'),
              selected='N')
)

#Make a reactive data.frame to be used with the nls function
test2=reactive(test%.%select(A,input$sample.choice))

#Display the data.frame
renderDataTable(test2())

#Use nls solver to determine a constant with a given formula:
c.fit=reactive(nls(A ~ I(C*input$sample.choice),data=test2(),start=list(C=1)))
renderText(summary(c.fit()))
```
````

I get as output `Error: non-numeric argument to mathematical function` after the call to renderDataTable and to renderText.

Can anybody help me figure out what is wrong here?

**Update**

Based on @wch comments, I have fixed the dplyr `select` function. I was also trying to call `renderText`, but the output of `summary.nls` is of type list. This won't work, and I needed to run `renderPrint` instead. See below for working code:

````
```{r, echo=TRUE}
require(dplyr)
test=data.frame(A=runif(n=10),V=runif(n=10),N=runif(n=10))

inputPanel(
  selectInput('sample.choice', label = 'Choose Columns',
              choices = c('V Sample'='V',
                          'N Sample'='N'),
              selected='N')
)

renderText(input$sample.choice)

test2=reactive(test%.%select(A,matches(input$sample.choice)))

renderDataTable(test2())

renderPrint({
  data=test2()
  formula=paste0('A ~ I(C*',input$sample.choice,')')
  c.fit=nls(formula,data=data,start=list(C=1))
  summary(c.fit)
})

```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that this line:

```
test %>% select(A, input$sample.choice)
```

ends up resolving to something like this:

```
test %>% select(A, "V")
```

But dplyr needs this because it uses non-standard evaluation:

```
test %>% select(A, V)
```

This is a possible workaround:

```
test %>% select(A, matches(input$sample.choice))
```

Comment: Using `matches()` fixes the dplyr issue. I get a different error after the call to `nls()` which reads `Error: parameters without starting value in 'data': sample.choice`. Any idea here? I tried wrapping the argument in `eval(input$sample.choice)` to no avail.

Comment: I think you'll also have to build the formula from a string. Something like `fmla <- as.formula(paste0("A ~ I(C*", input$sample.choice, ")"))` and then `nls(fmla, ...)`